# Time analysis of daily data w/ pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timeseries of observations with a resolution of one minute for several non continuous but complete days. The data is organized as a pivot table with days on the columns and times on the rows.

```
          2006-01-21  2006-01-24     ...      2006-02-08  2006-03-22
00:00:00        5.80        4.14     ...            7.03        4.27
00:01:00        4.71        5.22     ...            7.04        5.66
00:02:00        4.82        5.57     ...            4.11        5.04
00:03:00        3.20        4.11     ...            7.38        4.79
00:04:00        2.67        4.08     ...            6.39        6.91
```

I have to perform statistics on observations happening at the same time in different days, also considering the effects of time aggregation (resampling).

```
          Mean  StD
00:00:00   ...  ...
00:01:00   ...  ...
00:02:00   ...  ...

          Mean  StD
00:10:00   ...  ...
00:20:00   ...  ...
00:30:00   ...  ...
```

For now I am just keeping the dataframe as a pivot table, converting the index and columns to respectively a `datetime.time` and `datetime.date` object, but I have issues when:

- Trying to select columns beetween two dates
- Resampling the dataframe to a coarser time resolution (e.g. 10 mins)

Can you suggest the most effective way to structure the dataframe for this kind of operation?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to reshape the data to only have three columns: date, time, value. That way you can do your aggregations doing `groupby` by time. Selecting between two dates becomes easier because you are now selecting rows and not columns. Resampling isn't actually affected by it and depends on your resampling method.